# How many ways can 10 people be seated in a row if 3 people always sit in a group?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My attempt not sure if it is correct:
There are 6 different ways that the 3 people can sit in a group.
There are 8 different positions that the group can sit on the row, starting with zero people on their left and ending with zero people on their right.
The 7 remaining people can sit in 7 chairs 7! ways.
My answer: (6)(8)(7!) = 214,920 ways

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but more simply obtained as $8!\times3!$ [$8$ objects including group of $3$ permuted and group permuted]

Comment: Consistent with @trueblueanil's comment I regard the group of $~3~$ as fusing into one unit.  So, you have one fused unit that can be internally permuted in $~3!~$ ways, and a total of $~8~$ units to permute, $~7~$ of the original units and the single fused unit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

$3$ people sitting in a group affects the decisions that the others make. In other words, trying to find a solution with a single factorial will not work because there is no "*basic element*" (Without the group, the "*basic element*" would be one person). Therefore, any operation based on $10!$ will not work. Observe that if you *fuse* the group of $3$, by the fashion of @user2661923's comment, you can replace $3$ spots for $3$ people to sit in with $1$ spot for a group to sit. This is because now there is a similar "*basic element*" to work with. Now, the problem becomes $8\;\times7\;\times\dots\times1=40320$, because there are $8$ remaining slots. Finally, remember that the order of the people in the group can change. Thus, the solution is $40320\;\times3!=214920$, which is what you had obtained.